# Getting Error: invalid UTF-8 sequence - bad continuation byte

Tags: netezza

I'm inserting into a table from an external csv file and one of the fields in that file has non-ascii characters. An example of the character is this: `É`.

Here is my insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE
    SELECT * FROM 
    EXTERNAL 'C:\MyCSVFolder\external_table.csv'
    USING (
        DELIMITER '|'
        Y2BASE 2000
        ENCODING 'internal'
        REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC'
        ESCAPECHAR '\'
        MAXERRORS 10
        LOGDIR 'C:\MyLogFolder'
    );
```

When I look through my log file, I notice that the operation gets cancelled because values in one of my fields has an `É`. The error is: **invalid UTF-8 sequence - bad continuation byte**

How can I solve this? I can't change my csv file since it is a huge file and all values should remain the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated!